# Java HttpsServer

Tags: java, https

Здравствуйте.
Я хотел сделать локальный https сервер на компьютере.
Я не могу использовать класс `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer`.
Помогите разобраться.

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 5);
        server.createContext("/", new HttpHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
                byte[] data = ("welcome to my web site " + Math.random()).getBytes();
                httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, data.length);
                OutputStream out = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
                out.write(data);
                out.close();
            }
        });
        server.start();
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at Main.main(Main.java:52)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали? Может код какой есть посмотреть?

Comment: а зачем вам https сервер?

Comment: хотел сделать proxy server

Answer (score 0):

В случае если стандартной библиотекой, то нужно сгенерировать keystore [Вот тут подробно для -nix](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2121490-java-keytool---create-keystore) и настроить траст, это всё будет выглядеть примерно так: (Взято отсюда [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308479/simple-java-https-server) )

```
final HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1])), BACKLOG);
        final SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        final FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("ssl.jks");
        final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        final char[] storepass = "SSLAuth".toCharArray();

        keyStore.load(fileInput, storepass);

        final KeyManagerFactory kmg = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmg.init(keyStore, storepass);

        final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        ssl.init(kmg.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(ssl) {
            @Override
            public void configure(HttpsParameters params){
                try
                {
                    // initialise the SSL context
                    SSLContext c = SSLContext.getDefault ();
                    SSLEngine engine = c.createSSLEngine ();
                    params.setNeedClientAuth ( false );
                    params.setCipherSuites ( engine.getEnabledCipherSuites () );
                    params.setProtocols ( engine.getEnabledProtocols () );

                    // get default parameters
                    SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = c.getDefaultSSLParameters ();
                    params.setSSLParameters ( defaultSSLParameters );
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                }
            }
        } );
```

Но проще либо использовать Spring Boot либо развернуть Apache Tomcat и задеплоить сервлет. Т.к. подобная реализация не очень производительна и вообще с ней много проблем.

1. [Как настроить Apache с поддержкой HTTPS](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)
2. [Как писать сервлет](http://devcolibri.com/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-servlet-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE/)
3. [Spring Boot HTTPS](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/)